# Attach event handler to every li

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventhandler

I have this code and I want to attach DIFFERENT event handlers to every `<a>` without using id or class. 
I tried this but didn't work...

```js
$('#points ul li a').on('click', function(event) {
  // I don't know why this selectors doesn't work
  if ($(event.target).is(':eq(0)')) {
    alert('0') // and do something
  }
  if ($(event.target).is(':eq(1)')) {
    alert('1') // and do something 
  }
  if ($(event.target).is(':eq(2)')) {
    alert('2') // and do something
  }
})
```

```css
#points ul {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 5em;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: .5em;
}
#points ul li {
  float: left;
}
#points ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey;
  padding: .1em;
  line-height: .1em
}
#points {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="points">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">.</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">.</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">.</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All the answers are correct. But when I inserted the code inside the main html of the webpage it didnt work, and after struggling my head for some time I realized why: Inside the main html there are more <a> tags before, so this code, for example: ( e.is ( 'a:eq(1)' ) will match the very first <a> in the page, not the very first <a> inside #points div wich was the real objective. I was wondering if possible to target the first <a> tag of #points in some fashion different than counting the number of <a> tags in the whole page. Thanks.

Comment: `#points>ul>li>a:eq(0)` will do the trick. it will take only `a` inside `li` inside `ul` inside `#points`. My answer already had this. check the snipeet example.

Comment: That worked!! Could it be possible to do something like this? num = 1;
  $ ( '#points>ul>li>a:eq("num")').toggleClass ( 'color' );

Comment: `$('#points>ul>li>a:eq(' + num + ')')` is the right way to do that. cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help mate!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As suggested there are many alternate solutions, but the specific
   **error in your code was regarding your usage** of `:eq(0)`. Change it to    `#points>ul>li>a:eq(0)` as per the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) .

   REPLACE

   ```
   if ($(event.target).is(':eq(1)')) {
   ```

   WITH

   ```
   if ($(event.target).is('#points>ul>li>a:eq(0)')) {
   ```

   **Note: I have used `#points>ul>li>a` so that other `<a> tags` above and below are not selected. ( in light of your comment regarding the same )**
2. I want to just add that if I was asked to do the same I'd take an
   approach like:

   ```
   var objArr = $('#points>ul>li>a');
   objArr.on('click', function(event) {
     switch($(objArr).index(this)){
       case 0:
         alert('0');
         break;
       case 1:
         alert('1');
         break;
       case 2:
         alert('2');
         break;
     }
   });
   ```

---

That said your method works too and the **WORKING EXAMPLE *with the error I mentioned above adjusted*** for:

```js
$('#points>ul>li>a').on('click', function(event) {
  // I don't know why this selectors doesn't work
  if ($(event.target).is('#points>ul>li>a:eq(0)')) {
    alert('0') // and do something
  }
  if ($(event.target).is('#points>ul>li>a:eq(1)')) {
    alert('1') // and do something 
  }
  if ($(event.target).is('#points>ul>li>a:eq(2)')) {
    alert('2') // and do something
  }
})
```

```css
#points>ul {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 5em;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: .5em;
}
#points>ul>li {
  float: left;
}
#points>ul>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey;
  margin: .1em;
}
#points>ul>li>a {
  background-color: yellow;
}
div {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#">random link</a>
  <a href="#">random link</a>
  <a href="#">random link</a>
</div>
<br />
<div id="points">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">.</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">.</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">.</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div>
  <a href="#">random link</a>
  <a href="#">random link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Include `a` selector before `:eq()`

```js
$('#points ul li a').on('click', function(event) {
  var el = $(event.target);
  if (el.is('a:eq(0)')) {
    alert('0') // and do something
  }
  if (el.is('a:eq(1)')) {
    alert('1') // and do something 
  }
  if (el.is('a:eq(2)')) {
    alert('2') // and do something
  }
})
```

```css
#points ul {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 5em;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: .5em;
}
#points ul li {
  float: left;
}
#points ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey;
  padding: .1em;
  line-height: .1em
}
#points {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="points">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">.</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">.</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">.</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var items = $('#points li a');

$('#points ul li a').on('click', function(event) {

  var currentItem = event.currentTarget
  
  if (items.index(currentItem) === 0) {
    alert('0') ;
  }
  if (items.index(currentItem) === 1) {
    alert('1') ;
  }
  if (items.index(currentItem) === 2) {
    alert('2');
  }
})
```

```css
#points ul {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 5em;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: .5em;
}
#points ul li {
  float: left;
}
#points ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey;
  padding: .1em;
  line-height: .1em
}
#points {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="points">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">.</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">.</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">.</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```